# How to choose proper method for scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: minimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I was wondering how I can choose the best minimization method for scipy.optimize.minimize and how different the results may be?

I am trying to minimize the following expression (solve for g):

`|a1.g.x + a2.g.x^3 - K|`

Answer (score 21):

Scipy has a lecture on Mathematical Optimization, where they have a [section on choosing a minimization method](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#choosing-a-method). Snippet taken from that section:

> **Without knowledge of the gradient:**
>
> - In general, prefer BFGS or
>   L-BFGS, even if you have to approximate numerically gradients. These
>   are also the default if you omit the parameter method - depending if
>   the problem has constraints or bounds
> - On well-conditioned problems,
>   Powell and Nelder-Mead, both gradient-free methods, work well in high
>   dimension, but they collapse for ill-conditioned problems.
>
> **With knowledge of the gradient**:
>
> - BFGS or L-BFGS.
> - Computational overhead
>   of BFGS is larger than that L-BFGS, itself larger than that of
>   conjugate gradient. On the other side, BFGS usually needs less
>   function evaluations than CG. Thus conjugate gradient method is better
>   than BFGS at optimizing computationally cheap functions.
>
> **With the Hessian**:
>
> - If you can compute the Hessian, prefer the Newton method (Newton-CG or TCG).
>
> **If you have noisy measurements**:
>
> - Use Nelder-Mead or Powell.

If I have interpreted your equation correctly, I think that either `BFGS or L-BFGS` might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I find that lmfit works much better on real data.  I have a problem where lmfit finds the coefficients for 15 parameters used for a non-linear system.
lmfit ( Levenberg_Marquardt ) is 5 times a faster than the minimize's L-BFGS-B which is in second place and BFGS which comes in third.  None of the others converge.  Since this is real data, the Jacobian and Hessian are not available.  I like Nelder-Mead when then number of parameters is small.